# Common output from two proximity sensors

Tags: digital-logic, proximity-sensor

I need help wherein I'm using proximity sensors to trigger an event in a device. The device looks for 12V from the sensors and registers it as an event trigger.

There's no problem when I'm using one sensor. However, could anyone suggest a good logic for using two sensors? Both will be connected to the same port of the device as I can allot only one.

The best solution I can come up with is using a timer relay to switch off output from one sensor so that when the other sensor is active, it can then send the trigger to the same port. (Two sensors to detect two different events)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use OR-ing diodes as shown in the schematic below.
The pull-down resistor ensures the input of the device is low when no sensor is triggered.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTNmU0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>